# Defining a image directory in the config.php file

Tags: php, configuration-files

I have created a config.php file for my site. it seems to be working but the images are not displaying .

```
define('HOST' , $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('DIR_BASE',      HOST.'/m.pdi');
define('DIR_INCLUDES',    DIR_BASE . '/includes/');
define('VIEW_HEADER',   DIR_INCLUDES . 'header.php');
define('VIEW_NAVIGATION',   DIR_INCLUDES . 'horizontalmainmenus.php');
define('VIEW_FOOTER',   DIR_INCLUDES . 'footer.php');
define('DIR_IMAGES',   DIR_BASE . '/images/');

<img src="<?PHP echo DIR_IMAGES; ?>final-logo.jpg">
```

My image location looks like `http://192.168.1.8/var/www/html/m.pdi/images/final-logo.jpg`

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image path has to be relative to your web root

```
define('DIR_IMAGES', '/m.pdi/images/');
```

this means your web root /m.pdi/images/

Comment: I have just amended my post, didnt spot it was /m.pdi/images/

Answer (score 2):

```
define('HOST' , $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

This is wrong. You probably meant:

```
define('HOST' , $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

But even then the resulting path is wrong, because the host name should not really appear in a site-local link.

Answer (score 2):

What you get with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is:

> The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

You get system path with it `/var/www/html/`, you could do:

```
define('DIR_IMAGES', '/m.pdi/images/'); //relative path
//OR define('DIR_IMAGES', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/m.pdi/images/');

<img src="<?php echo DIR_IMAGES; ?>final-logo.jpg">
```

[$_SERVER more info..](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you confuse real path (on server) with an URL.

Look at your produced HTML, and you'll see what is wrong.